# Use a value in a 2D array of ints as a variable

Tags: java

I have this 2D array:

```
int[][] neighbours = { { 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // row
                  { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 } }; // col
```

I was wondering if its possible to use the values in this as regular int variables, so i could use for example `neighbours[6][6]` to make 2 int variables, one for row and one for column, row = 1, column = -1.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: `int x = neighbours[6][6];`?

Comment: `int[][]` does store `regular int variables`, I didn't understand the second part of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25

int[][] values = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
                   {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
                   {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 
                   {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
                   {21, 22, 23, 24, 25} };
```

Having a two-dimensional array is like having an array of arrays, so in my example, each "row" is an array of ints and you can group the columns by getting the nth element of each row. Here is the result of grabbing different numbers.

```
values[0][0] = 1
values[0][1] = 2
values[1][0] = 6
values[1][4] = 10
values[3][2] = 18
```

Now, say you want to get all the neighbors of the number 8. First, you need to know what position 8 is in:

```
values[1][2];
int y = 1;
int x = 2;
```

Next, add and subtract from x; then add and subtract from y to get the nearby values. I will include diagonals in this example.

```
int[] neighbors = new int[8];//We know there will be 8 neighbors in a square
int neighborCount = 0;

for (int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++)
{
    for (int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++) // We start at the number 2(position [0][1]), increment through 3, and 4, then go to next row and start at 2 again.
    {
        if (! (j == y && i == x)) //Don't want to include 8 itself.
        {
            neighbors[neighborCount] = values[i][j];
            neighborCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code would also need to account for going outside the bounds of the array. For example: there is no values[-1][-1]. Thats all the time I have but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
int row = neighbours[0][6]
int column = neighbours[1][6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the notion of 2D array.

Your array does not have a position `[6][6]`. You have defined 2 rows and 8 columns. The first index indicates which row you access, and the second indicates which column.

`neighbours[6][6]` means the 7th element in the 7th column (the first element in an array is denoted by index 0), which does not exist. I think the elements you want to access are actually stored in `neighbours[0][6]` and `neighbours[1][6]`.
Note that `neighbours[x][y]` represents only ONE element, whose position you indicate using two variables (that's why you call it two-dimensional array).

Aside from that, you can assign any value stored in that array to an int variable.

```
int anInt = neighbours[0][0] //In you case, that's 0
int anotherInt = neighbours[0][1] //And this one is -1
```